How to identify the order of execution in an SQL Server execution plan?
I'm learning about query tuning and execution plans in SQL Server. When I run a query in SQL Server Management Studio and examine the execution plan, how can I determine which operation is executed first by the SQL Server?
Also, is the order of the operators in the execution plan shown in the image below correct?

You cannot sequence operations that are performed in parallel. They happen at the same time. You cannot be sure which will start or end before similar tasks in the other execution line.

If it's a long running query, however, you can enable "Include Live Query Statistics" which shows SQL Server working through each of the nodes. Considering the above query completes in about 2-3 seconds, what you see may be minimal.

This might help: https://www.sqlshack.com/the-basics-of-parallel-execution-plans-in-sql-server/

@BartMcEndree so i do not normally need to worry about which one comes first in the case of looking at 1 vs 4 .. both 3 and 5 needs to be finished for 6 to happen right?

@psj01 you are correct

The execution plan is a tree. Each operator calls its child operators to get rows from them. In the case of a hash join in a serial plan first of all it will call GetRow repeatedly on the top subtree to consume all of its build input and then when it has the hash table built it will call GetRow repeatedly on the other input to get the rows from there to perform the hash join.

The blocking part of the hash join is the build input. Rows will start flowing upstream from it whilst operators 5 and 4 are still active. It doesn't need to wait to consume all of the rows from that input before returning any itself to its parent operator
